# Multi-objective optimization in pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

could you please share a well-structured tutorial or guide to implement multi-objective optimization in Pyomo?
I just found some Q&A which was a bit vague

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Pyomo does not have special facilities to handle multi-objective models. So there this nothing special to learn, and you can use any Pyomo text or tutorial.

You will need to formulate your problem in terms of single objective models. Arguably, the most popular schemes are a weighted objective or a lexicographic method. The last approach will require you to solve a number of models. Although the concepts may require a bit of thought, these methods are not difficult to implement.